# Genetic algorithm problem

Tags: algorithms, genetic-algorithms

This is a problem I found in an old exam in my school.
I have to solve this Genetic Algorithm problem:
N students $x_{1},..,x_{N}$ have answered a quiz of 10 questions (True or False questions) and have obtained scors $s_{1},..,s_{N}$ (score can go from 0 to 10).
From these scores we would likw to deduce what are the correct answers to each question.
I don't know where to start. For my population it is obvious that it is the set of list of 10 booleans. 
But for my fitness I don't what to choose since we don't have a rule to calculate score and we don't have the target (correct answers: we are trying to find)

Do you guys have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are only $2^{10} = 1024$ possibilities for the list of correct answers, so try all of them and see which one gives the correct scores.

If the number of questions is larger: Use integer linear programming; the problem can be straightforwardly expressed using integer linear constraints, and then can be solved with an ILP solver.  I expect this will be more effective than using genetic algorithms.